# Creating array of references to objects.

Tags: system-verilog

I am looking for way to simplify my code by creating array array with references to logic variables. This will let me to iterate across array. Here is pseudo code that i am envisioning (This is what i would do in C++). I can not put them in array as they part of RTL located in different places.

```
logic A;
logic B;
task my_algorithm();
  ref logic elements[2] = {A, B};  // This wrong, ref cannot be used in this           context
  foreach(elements[v]) begin
    // Do same work on each element
  end
endtask : my_algorithm
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inout` arguments that get copied in on entry to the routine, and then copied out upon exit from the routine. (use a function instead of a task, unless the routine needs to consume time)

```
function automatic void my_algorithm(inout logic A, B);
   logic elements[2] = {A,B};
   foreach(elements[v]) begin
      //
   end
   {<<{A,B}} = elements;
endfunction
```